# How to replace all occurences with regexp on prefix and suffix?

Tags: java, regex

```
System.out.println(
"ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")"
.replaceAll("ISODate\\(\".+\"\\)", 
    "ISODate(\"222\")"));
```

Result

```
ISODate("222")
```

How to replace all dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`".+"` is greedy, that will match a double quote and then the longest match before matching next double quote.

You can use non-greedy match:

```
System.out.println(
"ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")"
.replaceAll("ISODate\\(\".+?\"\\)", 
    "ISODate(\"222\")"));
```

Or better performing negated character class:

```
System.out.println(
"ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")ISODate(\"333\")"
.replaceAll("ISODate\\(\"[^\"]+\"\\)", 
    "ISODate(\"222\")"));
```